# Rails - Disable Nested Attributes in Mongoid / Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

In Mongoid embedded documents `accepts nested attributes` is on by default. How can one disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try use `attr_protected` macro?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `attr_protected` to restrict given attributes from being mass assignable or use the inverse `attr_accessible` to allow only the given attributes to be mass assignable.